# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in websphere 8.5.5 which occurs in production but not in UAT

Tags: aix

I am deploying a struts application in Websphere in production, which was signed off in UAT, but in production while deploying exactly the same war file it is giving the below error.

E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /JSP/NewCommercialSearch.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:733)
at com.ibm._jsp._NewCommercialSearch._jspService(_NewCommercialSearch.java:1132)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:198)
at com.creditwave.pl.agriworx.action.ActionServlet.doForward(ActionServlet.java:368)
at com.creditwave.pl.agriworx.action.ActionServlet.doTask(ActionServlet.java:340)
at com.creditwave.pl.agriworx.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:163)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:198

Answer (score 0):

a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`Typically occurs when the specific class, here `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory` is not found at runtime. If it worked on UAT but not in production, I would suggest to check if your two webspheres have everything aligned in term of libraries, I suspect there is something missing in production.

Comment: Supposing all the libraries are available in both the environments, could there be any websphere application configuration change we might be missing for this error?